# Wordpress multisite links are broken

Tags: php, wordpress, multisite

I created a multi site using wordpress multi site
the sub site http://new.flytpaths.com/flytnet/ 
it's styling links being broken and i can't access it's dashboard also

> This is my config file:

```
    $table_prefix = 'wp_';

    define('WP_DEBUG', false);
    define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true);
    define('MULTISITE', true);
    define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', true);
    define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'new.flytpaths.com');
    define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
    define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
    define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);

    if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) )
        define( 'ABSPATH', dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/' );

    require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php';
```

> This is my .hataccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ wp/$1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

How to fix it?

Comment: What is your chmod (access rights) for `new` folder and `flytnet` folder? Should be 755. You can access the wordpress admin dashboard at http://new.flytpaths.com/wp-login.php

Comment: how can i check it from cpanel ?

Comment: I dont exactly know cPanel, but if you have a CMD, you can CD to the folder and use `stat directory` or `stat -c %a directory`

Comment: i can access the dashboard at this link new.flytpaths.com/wp-login.php
but this is a multisite word press when i change to the dashboard of the sub site 
i get this message ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Comment: i opened the source of the broken site , when i removed 'flytnet' from any path to any style or js file it opened

Comment: Okay, so the problem is the chmod for flytnet folder.

Comment: when i accessed the folders don't see the flynet folder , i think the mutlisite wordpress merge them

Answer (score 0):

A lot of times when a db gets copied especially in a multisite, in the wp_X_options table the siteurl and home are forgotten. Check if they're correct too